# Simple java bot telegram: messages in loop

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make simple telegram bot on Java.

The question is: how can I receive messages in a loop, when the user typed `/start`? I have already some

```
@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    Message msg = update.getMessage();
    String txt = msg.getText();
    if (txt.equals("/start")) {
        sendMsg(msg, "Привет, меня зовут бот " + name + "!");
        showHelp(msg);
        run(msg, update);
    } else if (txt.equals("/help")) {
        showHelp(msg);
    }
}
```

Here's showhelp:

```
private void showHelp(Message msg) {
    try {
        String inAbout = ReadFile.readFileInString(this.about);
        sendMsg(msg, inAbout);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

sendMsg:

```
private void sendMsg(Message msg, String text) {
    SendMessage s = new SendMessage();
    s.setChatId(msg.getChatId());
    s.setText(text);
    try {
        execute(s);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In Run I want to read questions from data and wait for users answer, check if correct and do it in loop. In the end show how many he answered correct.

```
public void run(Message msg, Update update) {
        try {
            List<String> data = ReadFile.readFileInList(this.getData());
            List<String> dataAnswers = ReadFile.readFileInList(this.answers);
            this.sizeOfAnswers = data.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                String line = data.get(i);
                sendMsg(msg, line);
                String inAnswer = update.getMessage().getText();
                String rAns = dataAnswers.get(i);
                boolean flag = checkAnswer(inAnswer, rAns);
                if (flag) {
                    this.currentUser.incrementScore();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            String finalString = "Поздравляю, ты ответил на " + this.currentUser.getScore() + "/" + this.sizeOfAnswers
                    + " вопросов!";
            sendMsg(msg, finalString);
        }
    }
```

Also here is maybe some multi user problems. How should I do it? Now it's showing all questions in one second without waiting for an answer. 
[How it's working now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhzg7.png)

Comment: Why it's not a question?

Comment: You're asking how to receive messages in loop and post an answer to that question below. Stackoverflow is not a code review service. You're also asking bout some "multi user problems", but I got no idea what that means. Remove unnecessary text/code and clarify your problem, otherwise question is likely to be deleted.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov No, my bot isn't workin correct, he's giving all messages in one time, without waiting for an answer for question.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I added picture that shows how it works

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Stackoverflow, your answer helped me a lot